# How to Add Pagination to bottom-left of Jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

Here is the Jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').dataTable( {
        
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "dom": '<"top"f<"clear">>t<"bottom"ip<"clear">>'
    } );
} );
```

How to align the pagination to bottom left side ?

Comment: Did you used any styling framework (e.g.: Bootstrap 3/4, Foundation, JQuery UI, etc...)?

Comment: no, didn't use any styling framework.